# C# Web Form Application Sql Command

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

This is for getting datepicker value and there is no problem with this division

```
<div class="frame">
    <span class="firstdp"><span class="innerdp">
        <ej:DatePicker ID="daterange1" runat="server" ClientSideOnClose="selectedDate1" Width="80%" DateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" Value="2017-01-01"></ej:DatePicker>         
    </span>

    </span><span class="seconddp"><span class="innerdp">
        <ej:DatePicker ID="daterange2" runat="server" ClientSideOnClose="selectedDate2"  Width="80%" DateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" Value="2018-06-01"></ej:DatePicker>
    </span></span>
</div>
```

But in this case when I want to get datepicker values for SQL query, which are daterange1 and daterange2, every time I hit the crashes at below part.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" 
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:Valeo_DBConnectionStringSUNUCU %>'    
     SelectCommand="SELECT Id, Quantity, Code AS Reference, LotNo, Date, Supplier, ISNULL(ProductionType, '-') AS ProductionType, ISNULL(Shelf, '-') AS Shelf, ISNULL(Indis, '-') AS Indis, ProjectName, ISNULL([From], '-') AS [From], ISNULL([To], '-') AS [To], Whose AS Responsible, Type
                    FROM V_Stock
                    WHERE (Type = 'Entry' AND Date >= @'dateForSql1' AND Date <= @'dateForSql2') 
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT StockId AS Id, Quantity, Reference, LotNo, Tarih, Supplier, ISNULL(ProductionType, '-') AS ProductionType, ISNULL(Shelf, '-') AS Shelf, ISNULL(Indis, '-') AS Indis, ProjectName, ISNULL([From], '-') AS [From], ISNULL([To], '-') AS [To], Responsible, Type
                    FROM V_StockMovements  
                    ORDER BY ID DESC">
    <FilterParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="daterange1" Name="dateForSql1" Type="DateTime" DbType="DateTime" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="daterange2" Name="dateForSql2" Type="DateTime" DbType="DateTime" />
    </FilterParameters>                    
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this directly in the aspx file. You will run in a lot of issues, if you try to solve your problems with embedded sql in aspx. I recommend to put this outside your C# Code!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is 'Must declare the scalar variable "@dateForSql1"'.

Comment: As @ChristianMüller said, use the aspx.cs page for your SQL query, and then you can reference your two date fields using variables (daterange1.Value and daterange2.Value), either by directly embedding (less recommend) or using SQL parameters (recommended).

Comment: I know that thx for reccomendation but my framework is syncfusion and it is very slow at the start. And when i want to add some tool like button, label, datepicker etc. then program is not constructing automatically. so i couldn't get event of datepicker i tried but it was not effected on .cs side . It can be seen but not editable because of that i need to make it in aspx side.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove single quotes from parameter name. Also, use Between for records in 2 date range. Like below: Change the date format to MM/DD/YYYY of SQL Parameter.

```
 Date Between @dateForSql1 AND  @dateForSql2
```

Further, you can set a default value in the SqlParameter.

Comment: I used this but in this case i get new error which is 'must declare scalar variable for "@datasql1"'

Answer (score 0):

The solution for you problem, as far I could reconstruct it. You should not use "FilterParameters" but "**SelectParameters**" to use scalar variables in the query.

This construction worked for me as proof of concept:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" 
                       ConnectionString='Server=.;Database=Demo1;Trusted_Connection=True;'    
                       SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tblDemo1 where date>@DateForSql1 and date<@DateForSql2">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="daterange1" Name="DateForSql1" Type="DateTime" DefaultValue="01/01/2001"/>
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="daterange2" Name="DateForSql2" Type="DateTime" DefaultValue="01/01/2019"/>
        </SelectParameters>                    
    </asp:SqlDataSource> 

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="Horizontal">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type"/>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```